# Scanning LAN using ping and Gnu Parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, ping

I am trying to scan my LAN using ping, invoking using Gnu Parallel.   The code ideally will simply report those IP addresses which are up and strip out any verbose reporting.    The original code  (without parallel) which works well is:

`for ip in $(seq 1 254) ; do ping -t5 -c 1 192.168.0.$ip > /dev/null ; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "192.168.0.$ip UP" &   done`

However it is annoying with all the job completed messages (set +m is not helpful).   Running sequentially takes too long to poll each IP address.

The Parallel code so far which works (take out the --dry-run to execute) is:

```
seq 1 254 | parallel  --dry-run ping -t5 -c 1 192.168.0.{}
```

but trying to do

```
seq 1 254 | parallel  --dry-run ping -t5 -c 1 192.168.0.{} ';' [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "192.168.0.{} UP"
```

or variations of that, fail to achieve the objective.    Can anyone help with the test part here?

Comment: Try `... | parallel -j 64 'ping ... 192.168.0.{} && echo ...`

Comment: You can also drop the `seq ...|` part and use `parallel... ::: {1..254}`

Answer (score 1):

Cracked it - hope this is helpful to others.

```
seq 1 254 | parallel  ' ping -t5 -c 1 192.168.0.{} >/dev/null && echo 192.168.0.{} UP ' 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: @Mark Setchell - many thanks -  no pun intended but we did our answers in parallel!

Answer (score 0):

From the Gnu documentation,  a parallel timeout rather than ping timeout seems to be more efficient

```
seq 1 254 | parallel  --timeout 2 -j64 -keep-order ' ping -c 1 192.168.0.{} >/dev/null && echo 192.168.0.{} UP ' 2>/dev/null
```